# PHP Array doesn't show all database items

Tags: php

I fixed now my PHP file and finally I have an output of my array. But the problem is, that I have three entry of textes in my database, but my array only shows two of them.

**Function.php**

```
public function listQuestion(){

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT text FROM `questions`");

    if(!$result)
    {
      echo "Database query failed: " . mysql_error();
    }

  $temp_array = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $temp_array[] = $row;
  }

 return $temp_array;
}
```

**Index.php**

```
else if ($tag == "question"){
      // Request type is question
    // list questions
    $question = $db->listQuestion();
    if ($question != false) {
        // questions found
        // echo json with success = 1
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["question"] = $question;
       // $userlog = array();
      //  $userlog["question"]["text"] = $question["text"];
      //  array_push($response["question"], $userlog);

       echo json_encode($response);
        //echo json_encode(array("question"=>$question));
    } else {
        // questions not found
        // echo json with error = 1
        $response["error"] = 1;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Questions were not found!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

**The output**

> {"tag":"question","success":1,"error":0,"question":
>   [{"0":"Ich lese gerne technische Zeitschriften.","text":"Ich lese gerne technische Zeitschriften."},
>   {"0":"Ich habe Angst im Dunkeln.","text":"Ich habe Angst im Dunkeln."},
>   **{"0":null,"text":null}]}** -> here should be 'Manchmal fühle ich mich hungrig.'

Any suggestions?

Roman

Comment: check return value of `listQuestion()` before process it

Comment: Do `var_dump($question);` on *index.php* page to see whether you're getting all the rows or not.

Comment: Thank you for reply! When I do var_dump($question), I'm getting all rows of my database. So what's the problem in my php json code?

Comment: Output: array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(40) "Ich lese gerne technische Zeitschriften." ["text"]=> string(40) "Ich lese gerne technische Zeitschriften." } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(26) "Ich habe Angst im Dunkeln." ["text"]=> string(26) "Ich habe Angst im Dunkeln." } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(32) "Manchmal fühle ich mich hungrig." ["text"]=> string(32) "Manchmal fühle ich mich hungrig." } }

Comment: Hello, when I make a fourth entry in the table 'questions', the output is correct. But the thirth entry in my database is always {null, null}. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Warning: You are using an obsolete technique for querying the database. The `mysql_xxx()` functions have been obsolete for a very long time and have now been removed entirely from the latest PHP versions. You need to urgently consider switching to a more modern library -- either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Can you show your DB data?